# Waiting/jumping times of non homogeneous process on a state chain (almost Markovian)

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-process

When considering a chain of states from 0 to N in continuous time with constant up and down going transition rates, the jumping or waiting times are exponentially distributed. Now consider the following time dependent up rate and constant down rate,

$f_+(t)=α(1−e^{−βt})$

$f_−(t)=α.$

What is the best course of action to compute the jumping time distribution for such a case? Also, the memoryless property should not hold, due to the time dependence. It would not be correct to call it a Markov or Poisson process, wouldn't it?